# Obtaining magnesium oxide from magnesium hydroxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, home-experiment, safety

What's the simplest and safest DIY way to obtain magnesium hydroxide to magnesium oxide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magnesium hydroxide decomposes at 332 °C (630 °F) :

$$\ce{Mg(OH)2_{(s)} -> MgO_{(s)} + H2O_{(g) }}$$

So heat the magnesium hydroxide in a covered crucible. The released water will cause the particles of magnesium hydroxide to "explode" so you want to do this covered.